# Ceph configuration file and ceph-deploy

Tags: ceph

I set up a test cluster and follow the [documentation](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/).

I created cluster with command `ceph-deploy new node1`. After that, ceph configuration file appeared in the current directory, which contains information about the monitor on the node with hostname `node1`. Then I added two OSDs to the cluster.

So now I have cluster with 1 monitor and 2 OSDs. `ceph status` command says that status is `HEALTH_OK`.

Following all the same documentation, I moved on to section "Expanding your cluster" and added two new monitors with commands `ceph-deploy mon add node2` and `ceph-deploy mon add node3`. Now I have cluster with three monitors in the quorum and status `HEALTH_OK`, but there is one little discrepancy for me. The `ceph.conf` is still the same. It contains old information about only one monitor. Why `ceph-deploy mon add {node-name}` command didn't update configuration file? And the main question is why `ceph status` displays correct information about new cluster state with 3 monitors while `ceph.conf` doesn't contain this information. Where is real configuration file and why `ceph-deploy` knows it but I don't?

And it works even after a reboot. All ceph daemons start, read incorrect `ceph.conf` (I checked this with `strace`) and, ignoring this, work fine with new configuration.

And the last question. Why `ceph-deploy osd activate {ceph-node}:/path/to/directory` command didn't update configuration file too? After all why do we need `ceph.conf` file if we have so smart `ceph-deploy` now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple questions here.

1) ceph.conf doesn't need to be completely the same for all nodes to run. E.g. OSD only need osd configuration they care about, MON only need configuration mon care ( unless you run everything on the same node which is also not recommended) So maybe your MON1 has MON1 MON2 has MON2 MON3 has MON3

2) When MON being created and then added, the MON map being updated so MON itself already know which other MON require to have quorum. So MON doesn't counting on ceph.conf to get quorum information but to change run time configuration.

3) ceph-deploy just a python script to prepare and run the ceph command for you. If you read into the detail ceph-deploy use e.g. ceph-disk zap prepare activate. 
Once you osd being prepared, and activate, once it is format to ceph partition, udev know where to mount. Then systemd ceph-osd.server will be activate ceph-osd at boot. That's why it doesn't need OSD information in ceph.conf at all